# Is a ban on government workers wearing religious symbols a gezeirat hamalchut for which one would be obligated to give up his life?

Tags: halacha-theory, death, kippa-yarmulka, martyr

So, i haven't heard that anyone today is making this punishable by death, but still...

[France has a law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_law_on_secularity_and_conspicuous_religious_symbols_in_schools) that prohibits government workers from wearing religious symbols on their job. This naturally includes the kippa. [Quebec](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/09/10/us-quebec-religion-idUSBRE9890XY20130910) was also considering it (the article is from late 2013, i haven't seen anything newer).

According to the Rambam ([Yesodei Hatorah 5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1105n.htm)), during "שעת השמד" - a time of destruction, when the ruler outlaws some Jewish practices, it is a mitzvah to be a martyr and not comply with it. (See also: [*Self-sacrifice in Jewish law* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-sacrifice_in_Jewish_law)) I think i remember learning that this applies even to customs.

If the ban was actually so severe that you could be killed (and not just fired or fined), would this qualify for *yehareg v'al yaavor* - let him be killed and not transgress?

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, but for the record, until about 20 - 30 years ago many/most Yidden did not wear a head covering while at work. (Except when making a Bracha.)

Comment: http://www.lmaanyishmeu.com/pdf/79%20-%20The%20Yiddishe%20Image.pdf

Comment: There is no requirement to wear a "kippah" though, you could wear some other form of hat/cap that is not considered a religious symbol.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 157:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5092), the Ramma quotes a Beis Yoseif saying that *shaas hashmad* is only when the *gizeira* (decree) is specifically against Jews. The Shach there (#6) clarifies that if the *gizeira* is against the entire *medina* (country or jurisdiction), even though Jews are included, it is not called *shaas hashmad*.

Comment: I would like to add to this that the real reason for this גזירה is the moslems. Definitely not directed at the Jews.